# Working with OneNote Page Content via the Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I have a number of issues when working with OneNote via the graph api.

I understand that what OneNote uses is not straight html and they need to convert it back and forward for the API... but this would not appear to be that complex a task.

I am processing tags in the content and need to be able to update the tag element. It is fine except for where I have a list of items (p or li) tags where there are indents.

**UPDATED**

If there are items like this in my onenote

Dont have the rights to embed an image... so here is the link
https://xomq6w.ch.files.1drv.com/y4mc-mJZRhkI5c_fvOAbHGOnzEKVNKgxTHLop-OHfNofncLcC2gUc_Z_aYi0sgrc3hxIxxWpnvwRFc7p-reL5mX8J5pp1ePaY0V2McibdocMTplud7lxcso0EwAGJpHpBkcyLbcsLxDUpoYZ9T5XgCCxxmfUwQhHFPFQdFscfQoDPp7ZA-vCNbErgqyz0FK7prVaeMjs8LpiftMKu6-Xcv7Rg?width=160&height=541&cropmode=none

I hit the graph api to get the content with the following url via the graph api explorer

GET - https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myname/onenote/pages/0-c9861926a1e8080518ca3750afa63800!1-2B303C571455A20B!102505/content?includeIDs=true

the html that comes back will look like this (note that the indents are not there)

```
<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
    <div id="div:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{65}" style="position:absolute;left:264px;top:139px;width:624px">
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{67}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 1</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{74}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{71}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2a</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{73}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2b</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{76}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And if I patch the ones that have child items like this to set ids (leaving the id in there... turns it into a permanent data-id) for later updates or even to close a tag:

```
PATCH - https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myname/onenote/pages/0-c9861926a1e8080518ca3750afa63800!1-2B303C571455A20B!102505/content?includeIDs=true

[
  {
    'target':'p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{74}',
    'action':'replace',
    'content':'<p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{74}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2</p>'
  }
]
```

The update will be processed and then the content will be updated to this:

Image here: https://kw9psa.ch.files.1drv.com/y4mplcvzocTmhN9DZBpFt4Sic3AOpxe2Ik4r7VX_0Joxs5ay9woTUYZufKSr0ojcfwQckovsJv5__fSrDx1GqWK9cFa2yQ7uFPE8JQOBwPyYn6PQZHDMM4N9JB4IXF4Rs7dIDoqa0XYfjz93qGiI97Ais99l04QxWZyV1Og5eXRguUYlBoNTwXIuzFEbKZfA03mt_ynxXCjbM7CFHYP99_QgQ?width=160&height=134&cropmode=none

```
<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
    <div id="div:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{65}" style="position:absolute;left:264px;top:139px;width:624px">
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{67}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 1</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{71}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2a</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{73}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2b</p>
        <p id="p:{78cb2ca5-efec-4e6f-a763-12e9cac6a2b5}{2}" lang="en-US" data-tag="to-do" data-id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{74}" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2</p>
        <p id="p:{f115c5ea-0481-0f03-31aa-07b94321c323}{76}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The same essentially happens for nested ul/ol items... I also tried replacing the whole list instead of individual items, but the api call errors out with no additional information. Nested bulleted lists also seem to lose the parent bullet.

I have tried batching all updates for all items, doing one at a time, reversing the order.

Funnily enough if I do an insert then the text indents and order are retained, but there is no delete/remove patch to clean out the old text... e.g.

```
[
  {
    'target':'p:{56d579c0-1203-0224-0587-6fe03fb82539}{34}',
    'action':'insert',
    'position':'before',
    'content':'<p data-id="My_own_id" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 1</p>'
  },
  {
    'target':'p:{56d579c0-1203-0224-0587-6fe03fb82539}{34}',
    'action':'<tried replace or delete/remove hoping it was undocumented>',
    'content':'<tried blank or just a span>'
  }
]
```

Other issues include

- tables losing their show gridlines properties
- tags with no text not returning or even just disappearing if I update any text on the page

**Partial Answer**

Here is a partial answer for the non bulletted list issue... thanks to codeye for pointing me in the right direction.

By inserting my element before the existing one it retains the order.

```
[
  {
    'target':'p:{20781e6d-ba99-4fca-9994-622720cad7f8}{249}',
    'action':'insert',
    'position':'before',
    'content':'<p data-id="test" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Item 2</p>'
  }
]
```

Then removing the old one with the following it looks to retain the formatting. And as it is an empty div OneNote doesn't add the element.

```
[
  {
    'target':'p:{20781e6d-ba99-4fca-9994-622720cad7f8}{249}',
    'action':'replace',
    'content':'<div></div>'
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the request endpoint and request body on your side to the description.

Comment: I'm not seeing the behaviour you describe. Can you perhaps post a link or a screenshot to a sample page?

Comment: Added more details above... and specific urls and steps.

Comment: thanks Paul. I think I see whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for table borders

When work with tables use `border` attribute instead of `style`.

API returns you a table with borders as `<table style="border:1px solid;border-collapse:collapse">...</table>`. Use `table.style.border` to find if there is a border (it can be 1px or 0px). To set border for the table use `border` attribute: `<table border="1">...</table>`.

The `border` attribute for `td` will be ignored.

Comment: Just checked this out and it works. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

To the specific problem with the to-do list I can confirm the issue where the indented items shift up and "detach" from the element being updated.
It looks like the only reliable way to update a list with indents is to replace the entire list (a similar limitation is placed on tables).
In your example all 5 paragraphs seem to need to be updated to maintain alignment.
If that doesn't work try replacing the surrounding div

```
 [
      {
        'target':'div:{9dfa7be6-2de0-b802-01ae-20c164255f9d}{30}',
        'action':'replace',
        'content':'<div><p data-tag="to-do">Item 1</p>
                   <div><p data-tag="to-do">Item 2</p>
                        <ul>
                           <p data-tag="to-do:completed">Item 2a</p>
                           <p data-tag="to-do:completed">Item 2b</p>
                       </ul>
                   <div><p data-tag="to-do">Item 3</p>
                   <div><p data-tag="to-do">Item 4</p>
                  </div>'
      }    
]
```

As to how to remove an element the below should work

```
[{
      'target': 'p:{f5837c83-d816-4337-ab6d-a52abde869a6}{13}',
      'action': 'replace',
      'content': '<br/>'
    }]
```

This will not work in the middle of a list as you get a vertical gap.

Comment: Replacing the whole list in my sample will remove the indents. Replacing a li with a nested ul will work to a point however will insert a blank line before the ul. Neither solution seems satisfactory for an add in if I break the formatting.

Comment: OK. My last thought would be trying to replace the div content. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help... but unfortunately as the content I get back from the graph api doesn't show me which p's are indented... I wont be able to tell when to put a ul in there.

Comment: Wasnt sure whether to add a new answer or update the question with a partial answer... but have got one issue sorted... thanks codeye. Just need to address the bulleted list issue now and I may have a workable solution.

Comment: Well done. It's a pain that the individual elements give no indication of their level of indentation. I'll store away the trick for deleting unwanted elements. Thanks.