# Unable to make two changes in OneNote page

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I need to complete todos in user's page via MS Graph API. If todos are in a list, after replace operation for the todo the list becomes broken. Luckily, I found a hack to complete todo without breaking the list: [Working with OneNote Page Content via the Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52436703/1142300)

1. Insert a completed copy of a target todo before it
2. Replace the target todo with empty block

If I send these 2 operations in one request - API returns 500.

**Is it possible to fix it?**

---

Details about page and requests:

[image]

Page layout (`GET /me/onenote/pages/{{pageId}}/content?includeIDs=true`)

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Nested list</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="created" content="2018-10-04T09:46:00.0000000" />
    </head>
    <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
        <div id="div:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{144}" style="position:absolute;left:96px;top:139px;width:624px">
            <p id="p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{146}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Super task</p>
            <p id="p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{153}" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Point 1</p>
            <p id="p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{155}" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Point 2</p>
            <p id="p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{149}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Mega task</p>
            <p id="p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{151}" data-tag="to-do" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">Mega subtask</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update request (`PATCH /me/onenote/pages/{{pageId}}/content`):

```
[
  {
    "action": "insert",
    "position": "before",
    "target": "p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{146}",
    "content": "<p data-tag=\"to-do:completed\" style=\"margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt\">Super task</p>"
  }, {
    "action": "replace",
    "target": "p:{b883c993-0084-480b-9f15-3b0407435f29}{146}",
    "content": "<span></span>"
  }
]
```

API response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "19999",
        "message": "Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d352cd80-b40d-4d55-b984-2bb5cae07f2b",
            "date": "2018-10-04T04:24:25"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to just update one todo item should work. You can try replace the todos one by one.

Comment: If I perform an replace operation on todo, it breaks a list. You can see here how it looks after replace request: https://i.imgur.com/Nc7ZIgY.png

I'm going to post another question on this problem with more details

Comment: @SeiyaSu Here is a question from my colleague where is described, why I can't use a replace operation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52646010/1142300

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fix it?

Yes. By using the [batch request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching).

A workaround for you, I still working on format the body data:

```
   {
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "url": "/me/onenote/pages/{page-id}/content",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "body": {
        "value": [
          {
            "action": "insert",
            "position": "before",
            "target": "p:{04b55584-a5f7-4ac2-b34d-474ebe346ce8}{69}",
            "content": "<p data-tag=\"to-do:completed\" style=\"margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt\">Super task</p>"
          }
        ]
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "url": "/me/onenote/pages/{page-id}/content",
      "method": "PATCH",
      "body": {
        "value": [
          {
            "action": "replace",
            "target": "p:{04b55584-a5f7-4ac2-b34d-474ebe346ce8}{69}",
            "content": "<span></span>"
          }
        ]
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I didn't succeed to send a valid request. I've checked the documentation and it does not clarify how to send an array body. And I see you suggested to send an array as `value` field. I tried 2 ways: `body: [...]` - API responded 400, and `body: { "value": [...] }` - API responded 200, but individual requests failed (error code 20109). I saved requests and responses [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/zaverden/367374386aef6c03e2ee77cc69bfc2a9)